# Apache: How to run php files as CGI

Tags: php, apache, cgi, wampserver

How to run php as CGI in wampserver.

I want to run php files in this directory `c:/wamp64/www` as cgi.

I try to run cgi by following config:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp64/www/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .php
    Require local
</Directory>
```

but displays in error logs:

> malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: **Security Alert!** The PHP

How can i solve this problem and run php files as cgi?

Comment: You should never put anything in the `\wamp64\www` That folder belongs to WAMPServer. Create a subfolder like `\wamp\64\www\project1`